# Frontend React app fails to run on Google App Engine and loads forever then shuts down

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-app-engine

I currently have a backend web service written in golang deployed on Google App Engine running as the default service with the following app.yaml file:

```
runtime: go
env: flex

runtime_config:
  operating_system: 'ubuntu22'
  runtime_version: '1.20'

automatic_scaling:
  max_num_instances: 1
```

I also have a React web app written in Typescript that I would like to deploy as the frontend service pointing to another url, here is the frontend.yaml file for that:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: frontend

runtime_config:
  node_version: '16'

automatic_scaling:
  max_num_instances: 1
```

To deploy both of these services I have run the `gcloud app deploy app.yaml frontend.yaml`

The backend service is running perfectly fine and I'm able to access the api endpoints in there. However the react app seems to load infinitely and the web page is never shown, eventually it displays a 502 error and all I really see in the logs explorer on gcp is:

```
------------------------VM vm_name_here shutdown initiated-----------------------
Current app health: 0
Beginning service lameduck.
Triggering app shutdown handlers.
--------------App was unhealthy, grabbing debug logs---------------
Container CID file not found.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------Tail of app logs--------------------------
App logs not found.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I will include my package.json here as well for the react app:

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@devexpress/dx-core": "^4.0.4",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-chart": "^4.0.4",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-chart-material-ui": "^4.0.4",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-core": "^4.0.4",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-grid": "^4.0.4",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui": "^4.0.4",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.1.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.2",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.32",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "deck.gl": "^8.9.16",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.14.1",
    "maplibre-gl": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.9",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.0.24",
    "react-pro-sidebar": "^1.1.0-alpha.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "recharts": "^2.7.2",
    "supercluster": "^8.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "typescript-cookie": "^1.0.6",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=8080 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash.debounce": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/supercluster": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object":"^7.21.11"
  }
}
```

I have tried various different configrations to deploy the app with `gcloud app deploy frontend.yaml` but I can't seem to get the webpage up and running. Any thoughts on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Since the react app was originally running on port 3000 I tried changing it in the package.json to PORT=8080 for Google App Engine but the issue still persists.

Comment: Have you checked this documentation [Troubleshooting Response Error](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troub‌​leshoot-response-err‌​ors\#gae_errors) and [Breaking Change](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nod‌​ejs/release-notes\#A‌​pril_11_2023)?